# how to open webpage in webcontrol in c#

Tags: c#

i have url's of website in a list i want to open them one by one in a web browser using c#

Comment: Can you give a bit more information like:
When should this links be opened - when a user visits a website and clicks a button for example or you have your own windows application? Do you need to open the urls in different browser windows or one after another?

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply .
but i want to open that page in my webbrowser control one by one in a same forms.webbrowser control.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var url in urls)    
{
    Process.Start("iexplore.exe", url);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply .
but i want to open that page in my webbrowser control.

Comment: Then: `webBrowser1.Navigate(url)`. If you want to open all the urls you will need to create multiple forms each with it's own browser control.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just shell the URL, e.g.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

The web page will be displayed in the user's default browser.